# OracleSQL, I am stuck with listagg query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list like this:

```
cities                           firms
------                         -------
["NEWYORK"]                        1
["CHICAGO"]                        1
["LA"]                             1
["DENVER","VIENNA','LONDON']       2
["TORONTO"]                        2
["WASHINGTON",'VIENNA']            2
```

I want to replace the list with oracle sql like this:

```
cities                                     firms
------                                    -------
NEWYORK,CHICAGO,LA                           1
NEWYORK,CHICAGO,LA                           1
NEWYORK,CHICAGO,LA                           1
DENVER,VIENNA,LONDON,TORONTO,WASHINGTON      2
DENVER,VIENNA,LONDON,TORONTO,WASHINGTON      2
DENVER,VIENNA,LONDON,TORONTO,WASHINGTON      2
```

Comment: No result at all? Not even a simple query possibly with a syntax error? Also, can you elaborate about `["DENVER","VIENNA','LONDON']`  how is that stored? Is it a single field with a comma separated string of names?

Comment: yes exactly. its string field with comma separated. i have to group by citie names and remove duplicated cities and update this fields by firm id.

Comment: That's not an easy task, and not related to listagg (it's actually the reverse you are trying to do). It's actually bad practise to store the data like this in the first place. Do you have any possibility to normalize this data?

Comment: You may try [this creative solution form the OraFAQ forum](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/184666/) to split the strings so you have separate city names on different rows. After that, you can group by firm and aggregate the city names while removing any duplicates.

Comment: Are the `[` actually part of your data? And why there is a mix of single- and double-quotes ? Sometimes even not balanced: `"VIENNA'`. Please provide a sample of your _actual_ data.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that, maybe:

```
SELECT listagg("city", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "city") "cities",
       "firms"
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR("cities", '[^,]+',1, LEVEL) "city",
                  "firms"
  FROM T
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5 AND REGEXP_SUBSTR("cities", '[^,]+',1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
--                   ^
--          :/ Arbitrary maximum depth...
) V
GROUP BY "firms"
```

Producing:

```
|                                  CITIES | FIRMS |
|-----------------------------------------|-------|
|                      CHICAGO,LA,NEWYORK |     1 |
| DENVER,LONDON,TORONTO,VIENNA,WASHINGTON |     2 |
```

This is rather crude and probably need *a lot* more improvements. But this should give you some ideas to start from...

I have hard time to understand why this could be helpfull, but if you really need as much as duplicate records as in the original table, a simple `JOIN` will produce the desired output:

> ```
> WITH W AS (
> ```
>
> *the above query*
>
> ```
>     ) V
>     GROUP BY "firms"
>   )
>
> SELECT W."cities", "firms" FROM W JOIN T USING("firms");
> ```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/403e9/37